# Add path to assemblies to FAKE script

Tags: f#, f#-fake, f#-fake-4

Here is my FAKE build script:

```
#r @"packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake
open Fake.FscHelper

// Properties
let buildDir = "./build/"

// Targets 
Target "Clean" (fun _ ->
    CleanDir buildDir
)

Target "BuildApp" (fun _ ->
    ["src/app/Main.fs"]
    |> Fsc (fun p ->
              { p with Output = "build/Main.exe" })
)

Target "Default" (fun _ ->
    trace "Hello World from FAKE"
)

// Dependencies
"Clean"
  ==> "BuildApp"
  ==> "Default"

// start build
RunTargetOrDefault "Default"
```

My program use FSharp.Data which I have installed in `packages/FSharp.Data/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll` using `Paket`.

I can pass this path to compiler when I was building it from command line:

```
$ fsharpc src/app/Main.fs -r packages/FSharp.Data/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll
```

How can I do it in the FAKE script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify references using the `References` property of the record that the `Fsc` task uses:

```
Target "BuildApp" (fun _ ->
    ["src/app/Main.fs"]
    |> Fsc (fun p ->
              { p with 
                    References = [ "packages/FSharp.Data/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll" ]
                    Output = "build/Main.exe" })
)
```